# sublime text 3 and config Sass build package

Tags: sass, sublimetext, package-control

I use sublime text 3 
and install "Sass build" package

This is my project structure

```
/golden
 |----- css 
 |----- scss
          |--- test.scss
```

and I want to compile test.scss and show output in css folder. So I config package is :

```
[
   "cmd": ["sass", "--update", "$file:${file_path}/../css/${file_base_name}.css"],
]
```

But It isn't working. sublime show error report:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['sass', '--update', 'D:\\golden\\scss\\test.scss:D:\\golden\\scss/../css/test.css']]
[dir: D:\golden\scss]
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found this answer :

Please config

```
{
    "cmd": ["sass", "--update", "$file:${file_path}/../css/${file_base_name}.css"],
    "windows":
    {
        "shell": "true"
    }
}
```